# Outlook 2010 Room list empty but

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

I've created a room list and added rooms to it using this method http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2010/04/14/3409791.aspx but as in the room finder, i can see the group i created in the show room list, but in Choose available room it's empty, although in the suggested times i can see them.
As soon as i remove the cached mode for outlook i can see the rooms, and as soon as i re-enable the cached mode, they disappear. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you rebuild the GAL and download it to Outlook? If not it runs on a schedule and will happen *eventually*, though forcing them will make this much quicker.

Comment: unfortunately i did it...  [edit] i did it twice and it seems to work!

Comment: Worked for me! thanks! don't know why it wasn't working first time.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. It may have appeared by now, but the issue is related to the address book needs to be downloaded to the client.